# Displaying graph using database value from SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and need some help with this problem: I want two columns from a database table, i.e `age` and `name`, and use these values to populate a charts in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the time to read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to ask well-received questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you create charts/grpahs using asp.net mvc we can do it without help of any other frameworks such as [High Charts](https://www.highcharts.com/),[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)
first be clear with the overview of these things you can find some of the code samples from here. [DotNet Highcharts](http://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Gallery?demo=LineBasic&theme=default).